# Как установить приоритет чтобы label растягивался.

Tags: ios, swift

На экране  есть в первую очередь `ScrollView` у него констрейны `(top: 0, leading:0, trailing: 0, bottom: 0)`, под ней (в ней) находится `UIView` c констрейнами от `ScrollView` `(top: 0, leading:0, trailing: 0, bottom: 0, Align Center X)`
внутри этой `UIView` находятся сначала `UIImage`, затем `UILabel`, затем два `UIButton`.

`UIImage` находится сверху констрейны  `(top: 20, leading:20, trailing: 20, bottom: 40 (от UILabel))`

`UILabel` находится под `UIImage` c констрейнами `(top: 40(от UIImage), leading:32, trailing: 32, bottom: 40 (от UIButton))`

`UIButton` (Оформить подписку) находится под `UILabel` c констрейнами `(top: 40(от UILabel), Align Center X, bottom: 40 (от UIButton))` + фиксированная ширина 300 и высота 45

`UIButton` (Пропустить) находится под `UIButton` c констрейнами `(top: 8(от UIButton), Align Center X, bottom: 20)` + фиксированная ширина 300 и высота 45

Вот скрин как выглядит экран на данный момент.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И так вопрос, почему `UIView` поднялся за кнопкой, мне нужно чтобы последняя кнопка спустилась вниз, так как у нее констрейн bottom установлен 20 от `UIView`, а `UILabel` должен  расстянутсья.

Что я упустил, у меня такое ощущения что нужно указать где то приоритет, хотя не знаю где, потому что я не устанавливал для `UILabel` фиксированную высоту и он должен был растянуться

Вот скрин со сториборда, тут видно что `UIView` поднялась за `UIButton`

[image: Вот скрин со сториборда, тут видно что UIView поднялась за UIButton]

Comment: Скиньте storyboard с этим контроллером.

Comment: @VAndrJ вот залил на git hub https://github.com/muaviya/TestProject.git

Answer (score 0):

UPD
Если текста очень много, то можно сделать уменьшение текста. Если же нужен скролл, то вот один из вариантов:

[Вариант со скроллом](https://github.com/VAndrJ/TestStoryboardForSO/tree/withScroll)

Добавил на кнопку "Оформить подписку" чтоб добавлялось содержимое label для демонстрации.

---

В данном описании у Вас нужно исключить из иерархии Scroll View и все будет как хотите.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Ссылка на Ваш пример без ScrollView](https://github.com/VAndrJ/TestStoryboardForSO)

Comment: Но если к примеру текст большой, и он должен расстёгиваться, мне нужно думать о том, как это будет выглядеть на 4s. Поэтому я юзаю скролвью

Comment: @ИсмаилХасбулатов обновил ответ